# Page format before preview for printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a page like format with a background to display before asking to preview the page indicating that the color of the background will not be included in the preview. Thank You

```
        <script>
        function printContent() {
          var page = document.getElementById("page");
          var btn = document.getElementById("grey");

          btn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          page.style.borderStyle = 'none';
          page.style.margin = 'auto';

          window.print();
          btn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        </script>
        <div id="source-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="display: none;">&lt; &gt;</div></div><!-- /example -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS **@media print** feature. Instead of using JS, use CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{
            .btn{display:none}
            .page{margin:auto}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a [print stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/print-stylesheet-approaches-blacklist-vs-whitelist/) for this, then it will affect users who use browser actions (`CMD-P` for example) too

```
@media print {
  .btn {
    display: none;
  }
}
```